# marginal distributions of a joint pdf

Tags: statistics

find the marginal distributions of $$
  f(x,y) = 2xe^{-y}, \quad 0 < x,\quad x^2 < y
$$

I have drawn the support, with $y = x^2$.  Not sure how to proceed
(tried it on wolfram advanced calculus app and says it doesn't converge)

Comment: There are two different marginal distributions that you can compute. Does Wolfram claim that both integrals are diverge? If only one diverges, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The marginal in $x$ is 
$$
  \int_{x^2}^\infty 2xe^{-y} dy
= 2x \left. (- e^{-y}) \right|_{x^2}^\infty 
= 2xe^{-x^2}, \quad x > 0.
$$
The marginal in $y$ is 
$$
  \int_0^{\sqrt{y}} 2xe^{-y} dx
= e^{-y} \left. (x^2) \right|^{\sqrt{y}}_0
= ye^{-y}, \quad y > 0.
$$